# How to filter shell output to only number with decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, shell

I have CI/CD Config which required python version to be set to default by pyenv. I want to `python2 -V` output showed up with only, example, 2.7.18. But, rather than showing 2.7.18, it showing full text `Python 2.7.18` .

But, when I use it in python3 `python -V`, it showed the correct & current python3 version (`3.9.0`).

I use this code to try showing numbers only : `$(python -V | grep -Eo '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[10-19]')`.

And to set default with pyenv : `pyenv global $(python3 -V | grep -Eo '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[10-19]') $(python -V | grep -Eo '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[10-19]')`

So `pyenv $(python3 version) $(python2 version)`

Here is the image :

[Image of wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kypdx.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way would be to just replace the string Python with the emtpy string, if it exists.

Here a quick one-liner

```
python -V 2>&1| sed -e "s/Python//g" | xargs
```

That would print the python version, redirects stderr to stdout, replaces "Python" with "". Xargs without parameters returns the trimmed input string.

Comment: Yes, @stolzem 's answer worked. That's simple too, with just replacing Python word with empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more ways to get the version number:

```
# Print 1 word per line, the select the last word:
python -V 2>&1 | xargs -n1 | tail -n1

# Print the last word:
python -V 2>&1 | perl -lane 'print $F[-1];'

# Print the first stretch of 1 or more { digits or periods }:
python -V 2>&1 | grep -Po '[\d.]+'
```